# How can I invoke a thread multiple times in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm sorry if it is a stupid question. I am trying to use a number of classes of multi-threading to finish different jobs, which involves invoking these multi-threadings at different times for many times. But I am not sure which method to use. The code looks like this:

```
class workers1(Thread):  
    def __init__(self):  
        Thread.__init__(self)  
    def run(self):  
        do some stuff  

class workers2(Thread):  
    def __init__(self):  
        Thread.__init__(self)  
    def run(self):  
        do some stuff  

class workers3(Thread):  
    def __init__(self):  
        Thread.__init__(self)  
    def run(self):
        do some stuff  

WorkerList1=[workers1(i) for i in range(X)]  
WorkerList2=[workers2(i) for i in range(XX)]  
WorkerList2=[workers3(i) for i in range(XXX)]  


while True:  
    for thread in WorkerList1:  
         thread.run (start? join? or?)
    for thread in WorkerList2:  
          thread.run (start? join? or?)  
    for thread in WorkerList3:  
          thread.run (start? join? or?)  
    do sth  .
```

I am trying to have all the threads in all the WorkerList to start functioning at the same time, or at least start around the same time.  After sometime once they were all terminated, I would like to invoke all the threads again.

If there were no loop, I can just use .start; but since I can only start a thread once, start apparently does not fit here. If I use run, it seems that all the threads start sequentially, not only the threads in the same list, but also threads from different lists.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: When defining the Arrays shouldn't the second WorkerList2 be a WorkerList3 instead?

Answer (score 13):

there are a lot of misconceptions here:

- you can only start a specific instance of a thread once. but in your case, the for loop is looping over different instances of a thread, each instance being assigned to the variable `thread` in the loop, so there is no problem at all in calling the `start()` method over each thread. (you can think of it as if the variable `thread` is an alias of the `Thread()` object instantiated in your list)
- `run()` is not the same as `join()`: calling `run()` performs as if you were programming sequentially. the `run()` method does not start a new thread, it simply execute the statements in in the method, as for any other function call.
- `join()` does not start executing anything: it only waits for a thread to finish. in order for `join()` to work properly for a thread, you have to call `start()` on this thread first.

additionally, you should note that you cannot restart a thread once it has finished execution: you have to recreate the thread object for it to be started again. one workaround to get this working is to call `Thread.__init__()` at the end of the `run()` method. however, i would not recommend doing this since this will disallow the use of the `join()` method to detect the end of execution of the thread.

Comment: but it I am using the start() method in the loop, my program may actually give me a runtime error, saying that the thread is already started. So I am not able to invoke the run method within each thread again.

Answer (score 2):

If you would call `thread.start()` in the loops, you *would* actually start every thread only once, because all the entries in your list are distinct thread objects (it does not matter they belong to the same class).  You should never call the `run()` method of a thread directly -- it is meant to be called by the `start()` method.  Calling it directly would not call it in a separate thread.

Comment: If my thread is already started, and finished execution, how can I invoke the run method embedded within the thread again? My point was to call the run method within each thread multiple times

Comment: The `run()` method of every thread is only invoked once.  Write a loop inside `run()`, or use some producer-consumer pattern using the [`queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

The code below creates a class that is just a thread but the start and calls the initialization of the Thread class again so that the thread doesn't know it has been called.

```py
from threading import Thread
class MTThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, name = "", target = None):
        self.mt_name = name
        self.mt_target = target
        Thread.__init__(self, name = name, target = target)
    def start(self):
        super().start()
        Thread.__init__(self, name = self.mt_name, target = self.mt_target)
    def run(self):
        super().run()
        Thread.__init__(self, name = self.mt_name, target = self.mt_target)
def code():
    #Some code
thread = MTThread(name = "SomeThread", target = code)
thread.start()
thread.start()
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail (in your question) why and or how this solves the question? "Try this" doesn't help future readers

Answer (score 1):

I had this same dilemma and came up with this solution which has worked perfectly for me.  It also allows a thread-killing decorator to be used efficiently.

The key feature is the use of a thread refresher which is instantiated and `.start`ed in `main`.  This thread-refreshing thread will run a function that instantiates and starts all other (real, task-performing) threads.  Decorating the thread-refreshing function with a thread-killer allows you to kill all threads when a certain condition is met, such as `main` terminating.

```
@ThreadKiller(arg) #qu'est-ce que c'est
def RefreshThreads():
    threadTask1 = threading.Thread(name = "Task1", target = Task1, args = (anyArguments))
    threadTask2 = threading.Thread(name = "Task2", target = Task2, args = (anyArguments))
    threadTask1.start()
    threadTask2.start()

#Main
while True:
    #do stuff
    threadRefreshThreads = threading.Thread(name = "RefreshThreads", target = RefreshThreads, args = ())
    threadRefreshThreads.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
def runA():
    while a==1:
        print('A\n')
        sleep(0.5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a=1
    t1 = Thread(target = runA)
    t1.setDaemon(True)
    t1.start()
    sleep(2)
    a=0
    print(" now def runA stops")
    sleep(3)
    print("and now def runA continue")
    a=1
    t1 = Thread(target = runA)
    t1.start()
    sleep(2)
```