# How to stop and start a thread at will

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.6

So I'm doing some testing with threads and I realised I could not stop and then start a thread. I could stop it, but starting it again was the issue.
I want a script that adds 1 to a var when it is on then its stops when off by pressing shift to turn on and off.
I have the detecting shift working (it is on another part of my code), but I just need to find out how to stop and start threads
Here is my test code:

```
from threading import Thread as th
import time as t
var = 0
def testDef():
    global var
    var += 1:
    t.sleep(1)
test = th(target = testDef)
test.start()
while True:
    menu = input("On, Off, Show Var")
    if menu == "On":
        test.start()
    elif menu == "Off":
        test._stop():
    elif menu == "S":
        print(var)
```

I know there are a few errors, but I mainly need the on and off threading to work.
Thanks, Jeff.

Comment: At first there's a syntax error in your code at `var += 1:`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't actually stop and restart a thread as you can't use `test.start()` when the method has been terminated. However, you may be wondering to something similar by using `threading.Condition` to pause and later resume the execution.

You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects).

There is also an error in `var += 1:`, change it to `var += 1`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example on how to use `threading.Event` to enable two threads to communicate. This works by setting the internal flag of the Event to either True or False. While this internal flag is `False` you can ask thread `a` to `wait` (effectively block, which is not very efficient by the way). Then we use the two timers `(b, c)` to simulate a shift press every 5 seconds. In order to release `a` we `set` the event (internal flag = True). 5 seconds later, we `clear` the value of the internal flag and this will make thread `a` to block again.

```
import threading

def do(event):
    flag = True
    while flag:
        if not event.isSet():
            print "blocking"
            event.wait()
        else:
            print "resuming"


def pressShift(event, enable):
    print "Shift pressed"
    if enable:
        event.set()
    else:
        event.clear()

def main():
    event = threading.Event()
    a = threading.Thread(target=do, args=(event,))
    b = threading.Timer(5, pressShift, args=(event, True)).start()
    c = threading.Timer(10, pressShift, args=(event, False)).start()
    a.start()
    a.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas, but it seems that when I press shift its resumes but i have to press shift many times for it to recognise the shift again and go back to blocking. Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restart a thread that has already been started. What you can do, however, is to create another thread.

```
from threading import Thread as th
import time as t
var = 0
def testDef():
    global var
    var += 1
    t.sleep(1)
test = th(target = testDef)
test.start()
while True:
    menu = input("On, Off, Show Var")
    if menu == "On":
        test = th(target = testDef)
        test.start()
    elif menu == "Off":
        test._stop()
    elif menu == "S":
        print(var)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It seems that the variable is not increasing and the variable increases by 1 when you enter "On" but not any more after that unless you enter "On" again. Any reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [event object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524459/stopping-a-thread-after-a-certain-amount-of-time), and check that event in your target functoin. Also, you [need a new thread each time you re-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122188/how-can-i-invoke-a-thread-multiple-times-in-python).  The code shown below adds some debugging that should be useful. (Another approach is to build a [custom stop function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python).)

```
import logging
import threading
import time as t
var = 0

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
                    )

def testDef(stop_event):
    global var
    print 'Thread Running', var
    # inThread.stop()
    while not stop_event.isSet():
        var += 1
        logging.debug('Var is %i' % var) 
        t.sleep(1)

# Use an event to track user input
testStopEvent = threading.Event()
testStopEvent.clear()

test = threading.Thread(name = 'test', target=testDef, args=((testStopEvent,)))
test.setDaemon(True)
while True:
    menu = input("On = 1, Off = 2, Show Var = 3")
    if menu == 1:
        test.start()
    elif menu == 2:
        testStopEvent.set()
        test.join() # Wait for the thread to finish
        test = threading.Thread(target=testDef, args=((testStopEvent,))) # "re-start" thread
        testStopEvent.clear() # Reset the stop event

    elif menu == 3:
        print(var)
```